# Erro ao injetar Service dentro de um @component

Tags: java, spring

Defini um bean exemplo:

```
@Component
public class SimulationModelFactory {
```

e dentro da classe estou injetando meu service exemplo:

```
@Autowired
private SimulationFlowService simulationFlowService;
```

**Service sempre fica null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A anotação `@Autowired` vai tentar injetar alguma classe que implemente a interface `SimulationFlowService` (ou a própria classes).

Note que sua classe `SimulationModelFactory` não é nenhuma das duas. Tenta anotar `@Component` em um classe que implemente a interface.

Comment: SimulationFlowService  não é uma interface é um serviço.

Comment: Certo, mas ele é diferente de `SimulationModelFactory`. Anote ele com `@Component`.

Comment: Funcionou! muito obrigado mas ainda não entendi muito bem por que não funcionou com o @service.

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto, se estava anotada com `@Service` deveria funcionar sem problemas. Se está seguro que foi só esta alteração, eu não sei te explicar =).

Comment: só foi isso que alterei :|

Comment: Dê uma verificada na sua configuração. No [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894900/spring-autowiring-service-doesnt-work-in-my-controller) em inglês tem um problema semelhante ao seu.